# load corrupted xls file into r without manually changing file type

Tags: r, readr, readxl

I am struggling to download an excel file and then loading it to R:

```
utils::download.file(
  url = 'https://servicos.ibama.gov.br/ctf/publico/areasembargadas/downloadListaAreasEmbargadas.php',
  destfile = 'C:/users/arthu/Desktop/fines.rar',
  mode = "wb"
)
```

After unzipping and trying to load it into R:

```
utils::unzip(
  zipfile = './fines.rar',
  exdir = './ibama_data'
)


dados <- readxl::read_xls(
  "./ibama_data/rel_areas_embargadas_0-65000_2020-12-10_080019.xls"),
  skip = 6,
  col_type = c(rep("guess", 13), "date", "guess", "date")
)
```

I get `libxls error: Unable to open file`.

If I try to rename the file as .xlsx as follows, I get an evaluation error when reading it with `readxl::read_excel`, saying `unable to open file`

```
 file <-   file.rename(
      from = "./Desktop/ibama_data/rel_areas_embargadas_0-65000_2020-12-10_080019.xls",
      to = "./Desktop/ibama_data/test.xlsx"
    )
```

However, if I manually open such a file, excel throws me a warning saying that the file's extension does not match its type. After saving it as .xlsx, I can finally load it using `read_excel`

How can I solve this, given that I want to write a package with a function that downloads such data from the web and then loads it into R?

Edit

Comment: See `?file.rename`

Comment: @HongOoi After renaming to a .xlsx extension, I get the error that the file cannot be opened

Comment: are you sure you have the correct path to the file name? Have you tried "file.exists" to see if it exists before trying open it?

Comment: @DataMunger file.exists returns ```TRUE```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.xls` file you are trying to read isn't an Excel document, it's an HTML table.
You could read it using `XML` package :

```
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse('rel_areas_embargadas_0-65000_2021-01-13_080018.xls')
tableNode <- getNodeSet(doc, '//table')
data <- XML::readHTMLTable(tableNode[[1]])

#Store header
header <- data[1:5,]

#Store colnames
colnames <- data[6,]

#Remove header
data <- data[-1:-6,]

#Set colnames
colnames(data)<-colnames

head(data)
```

Comment: oh, thank you. How could I have known that? Because excel is in fact able to open the file if I try manually

Comment: When you can't open a file, try to read it in a text editor like `Notepad++` to figure out its real format, it often helps ;)